Команда card.wb.ru/cards/ обрезает название товара
У wildberries есть api команды, которые загружают информацию о товарах. Команда https://card.wb.ru/cards/detail?nm= выводит информацию о ценах и складах, а также имя товара. Но я столкнулся с неприятным эффектом, что, если имя товара длинное, то после определённого числа символов оно обрезается в выводе.
Кто знает, как можно получить полное имя товара по его nmId?
